# Sitecore Powershell - Namevaluelist field

Tags: powershell, sitecore

I am facing issue with NamevalueList field value, this field value spaces,special characters are replaced with Hex chars. For example spaces replaced with %20 and , < replaced with %3C, similarly all the  special chars are replaced by Hex. I have tried HTML Decode and URi decode but no luck. it was returning same value. Even Raw value of the field also showing the same. I am using Sitecore 8.1. Please refer the attached image
[image]

Could you please suggest how to solve the issue

Comment: Did you try to provide a minimum working example? This would help anybody who wants to answer your question. Please provide the code that is the problem for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the powershell solution, since it's a relatively quick one.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web
[System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlDecode('www.whatever%20%21%3C')
```